# Biopython: extract sequences not covered by any SeqFeatures

Tags: python-2.7, sequence, biopython

I am a self-educated starting bioinformatician and have the feeling I still need many workarounds to get things done. Anyway, this is my current question:

I have a DNA-contig, which I have BLASTed using a sliding window approach. As an output, I now have the sequences that are homologous to two separate subject BLAST-databases, and saved these as fasta-files. I would now like to extract the sequence that is NOT homologous to any of the subject databases.
I have already made a start by parsing the locations of the conserved regions, and creating a SeqFeature for each of these regions:

```
# list_of_confirmed_conservation_seqrecs contains the conserved seq records from both BLAST databases

def extract_LS_regions(directoryfolderfile, genome, list_of_confirmed_conservation_seqrecs):
    for contig_rec in SeqIO.parse(directoryfolderfile, 'fasta', IUPAC.ambiguous_dna):
        contig_id = contig_rec.id.split('contig_')[1]

        conserved_seqrecs_on_contig = []
        for conserved_seqrec in list_of_confirmed_conservation_seqrecs:
            conserved_seqrec_id = conserved_seqrec.id.split('contig_')[1].split('(bp')[0]
            if contig_id == conserved_seqrec_id:
                conserved_seqrecs_on_contig.append(conserved_seqrec)

        conserved_feature_locs_on_contig = []
        for conserved_seqrec in conserved_seqrecs_on_contig:
            conserved_seqrec_startbp    = int(conserved_seqrec.id.split('(bp')[1].split('-')[0])
            conserved_seqrec_endbp      = int(conserved_seqrec.id.split(')_on_')[0].split('-')[1])
            contig_rec.features.append(SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(int(conserved_seqrec_startbp)-1, int(conserved_seqrec_endbp)), type=conserved_seqrec.id, strand=1))
        contig_rec.features.append(SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(100, 200), type='testfeature', strand=1))
```

example of possible situation, because of comparing against multiple 
BLAST databases, each block '.--.' represents 100bp:

```
                  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
contig:         |---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---|
conserved1:     |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.---|
conserved2:     |---.xxx.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---|
```

In this case, I would like to extract block #10.

Is there a way to extract the sequences from the seq record that are *not* covered by a feature? I would like to rename these to 'contig_1_a(900-1000bp)'.

## -=[ EDIT: implemented xbello's strategy ]=-

as follows, and the code now seems to work. Thanks!

```
all_feature_locs_on_contig = [[100,500], [200,300], [400,600], [700, 800], [750, 900], [1000, 1300], [1500, 1800]]

"""To avoid changing the list you are iterating on, you make a copy of all_feature_locs_on_contig, 
iterate over it and remove the items from all_feature_locs_on_contig_B. Then you copy b (the altered copy) back to a."""

result_list = []    # collects all regions that contain 1 or more features (=conserved regions)
while len(all_feature_locs_on_contig) != 0:
    #get lowest start location
    #print 'complete list: ', all_feature_locs_on_contig
    current_result_list = min(all_feature_locs_on_contig, key=lambda p: min(p[0:]))
    all_feature_locs_on_contig.remove(current_result_list)
    all_feature_locs_on_contig_B = copy.copy(all_feature_locs_on_contig)
    #print 'removed lowest starting point feature: ', all_feature_locs_on_contig_B
    for feature in all_feature_locs_on_contig:
        if feature[0] <= current_result_list[1]:
            if feature[1] <= current_result_list[1]:    #EMBEDDED
                #print '\nEMBEDDED: ', (feature[0], feature[1])
                all_feature_locs_on_contig_B.remove(feature)
            elif feature[1] >= current_result_list[1]: #OVERLAPPING
                #print '\nOVERLAPPING: ', (feature[0], feature[1])
                current_result_list[1] = feature[1]
                #print 'changed current_result_list end position: ', current_result_list
                all_feature_locs_on_contig_B.remove(feature)

    all_feature_locs_on_contig = copy.copy(all_feature_locs_on_contig_B) #copy back to original list, after modifications.
    result_list.append(current_result_list)
print 'result_list: ', result_list


#now extract non_covered regions:
non_covered = []
for result in result_list:
    if result == result_list[0]:
        if result_list[0][0] != 0:
            region_a = [0,result_list[0][0]]
            non_covered.append(region_a)
        else:
            if len(result_list) <= 1:
                region_a = [result_list[0][1], len(contig_rec.seq)]
                non_covered.append(region_a)
        previous = result
    elif result != result_list[0]:
        if result != result_list[-1]:
            region_bcd = [previous[1], result[0]]
            non_covered.append(region_bcd)
            previous = result
        elif result == result_list[-1]:
            region_y = [previous[1], result[0]]
            non_covered.append(region_y)
            region_z = [result[1], len(contig_rec.seq)]
            non_covered.append(region_z)
print 'non_covered areas: ', non_covered,'\n'


i = 1
for noncovregion in non_covered:
    print '>'+genome+'_contig_'+str(contig_id)+'_'+str('{0:05}'.format(i))+'_noncoveredregion:'+str(noncovregion[0]+1)+'-'+str(noncovregion[1])+'bp'
    print contig_rec.seq[noncovregion[0]:noncovregion[1]]+'\n'
    i+=1
```

This yields:

```
result_list:  [[100, 600], [700, 900], [1000, 1300], [1500, 1800]]
non_covered areas:  [[0, 100], [600, 700], [900, 1000], [1300, 1500], [1800, 1864]]
```

followed by the sequences that I want to extract. Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct method in Biopython to get them. But you can get the points by doing this:

1. Get a list with the "original" FeatureLocation points.
2. Select the FeatureLocation with the lowest starting point, pop it from the list and put it in a "reference", cycle all other FeatureLocations:

   - Embedded: the starting point is lower than the ending of the reference, but the ending point is also lower than the ending point of reference, pop and discard.
   - Overlapped: the starting point is lower than the ending of the reference, but the ending is greater. Modify the "reference" ending point to this ending point, pop and discard.
   - Not overlapped: the starting point is higher than ending of reference. Do nothing.
3. Put "reference" in a "result_list".
4. Pass the two lists ("result_list" and "original") to the same method recursively.

E.g.

```
result_list = []
original_list = [(100, 500), (200, 300), (400, 600), (700, 800), (750, 900)]

Step 1:
result_list = [(100, 600)]
original_list = [popped, popped, popped, (700, 800), (750, 900)]

Step 2:
result_list = [(100, 600), (700, 900)]
original_list = [popped, popped, popped, popped, popped]
```

Now "negate" the points in the result list. Cycle through the "result_list" and:

1. The first point is (0, starting_point_of_first)
2. The following points are (ending_point_of_previous, starting_point_of_this)
3. The last point is (ending_point_of_previous, len(sequence))

E.g.

```
non_covered = [(0, 100), (600, 700), (900, 1000)]
```

---

```
def drain_seqs(remaining, done=[]):

    if remaining:
        reference = remaining.pop(0)

        if remaining and remaining[0][0] <= reference[1]:
            if remaining[0][1] > reference[1]:
                # It's overlapping
                reference[1] = remaining[0][1]
            # Delete overlapped and embedded
            remaining.pop(0)
            # And insert modified reference at the beginning
            remaining.insert(0, reference)
        else:
            # Next is not overlapped or this is the last one
            # Archive the reference and continue
            done.append(reference)

        drain_seqs(remaining, done)

    return done


sample_list = [[400, 650], [100, 500], [200, 300], [400, 600],
               [700, 800], [750, 900]]

sample_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

print drain_seqs(sample_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took me some time to figure it out (e.g. getting the feature with the lowest start location, but managed in the end:
`current_result_list = min(all_feature_locs_on_contig, key=lambda p: min(p[0:]))`

I will add the full code of what I created to the original post (don't know how to add large blocks of code into a comment..)
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can pass a sorted list, with the lowest start location at the first point. When I work with lists in this way, often I resort to recursive functions. I'm adding one to my answer. Recursion is cool!